# Is the constant value ignorable?

Tags: regression, spss, regression-coefficients, linear

I am running a linear regression on SPSS. Basically I have 2 independent and 1 dependent variables; and I would like to understand which of my independent variable is more effective on the dependent variable.

When I put the constant value into the equation, it does not give significant results. However, when I don't put the constant value into the equation, it gives significant results and of course it gives a value for each variable. So, I can understand, which one is more effective.

Actually, my aim is not creating a model. I just would like to compare the effects of 2 independent variables? So can i ignore the constant value then?

Comment: You might be interested in my answer to this question. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146042/significance-of-intercept-as-portrayed-via-an-r-formula/146044#146044

Comment: I understand what you mean, but still i would like to ask comparison. Can i compare the B values of 2 independent variables in the equation which has no constant value. Because it is still an equation isnt it?

Comment: Well, it is "still an equation" (however that means), but as explained in the linked answer, omitting the intercept will make the other coefficients biased. So **don't**